# what to do is it says:- Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: java

error is:-
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at AndroidManifest.xml:49:9-51:51 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided. woobox_droid.app main manifest (this file), line 48 Error: Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml:53:9-55:70 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided. woobox_droid.app main manifest (this file), line 52

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iqonic.woobox">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".WooBoxApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BlogDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AboutActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SubCategoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProductDetailActivityNew"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".AppBaseActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SignInUpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OTPActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.WalkThroughActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DashBoardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OrderDescriptionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OrderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--<activity
        android:name=".activity.ProductDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/CollapsingTheme" />-->
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BlogActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AddAddressActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OrderSummaryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.TrackItemActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PaymentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyCartActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ViewAllProductActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AddressManagerActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EditProfileActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.EmailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ContactUsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.FAQActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.OfferActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ReviewsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled"
        android:value="@bool/FIREBASE_CRASH_ENABLED" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/path" />
    </provider>

    <!-- Enable only if you are want Onesignal support-->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
        android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```